# Problem with messages framework in Django 1.2

Tags: django, django-templates

I'm running Django 1.2 beta and trying out the new feature: message framework.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/

Everything seems to work, but when I try to output the messages, I get nothing. Seems that `messages` variable is empty. I double checked all the settings, they seem to be just like in the manual. What could be wrong?

**settings.py**

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', #send messages to users
    'django.middleware.locale.LocaleMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',

    #debug tool
    'debug_toolbar.middleware.DebugToolbarMiddleware',
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages', #send messages to users
    'django.core.context_processors.auth',
)

#Store messages in sessions
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage';

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    #'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.messages', 
    'debug_toolbar',

    #my apps
    #...
)
```

**views.py**

```
def myview(request):

    from django.contrib import messages

    messages.error(request, 'error test');   
    messages.success(request, 'success test');   

    return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', locals());
```

**mytemplate.html**

```
{% for message in messages %}
        {{ message }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

In template nothing is outputted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll need to use a `RequestContext` in your call to `render_to_response`.

```
return render_to_response('mytemplate.html', locals(),
                          context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

See the note a few screens down under [this documentation section](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#playing-with-context-objects).

Comment: Tkank you! Needed to add from django.template import RequestContext as well